# Python logger not printing out 'extra' dictionary info

Tags: python, dictionary, logging

In my python code I pass a dictionary into the logger for example.

```
extra_info = {"test":"data"}
logger.info("",extra=extra_info)
```

My hope is to get the extra info to print and I assumed it was in the message but when I use this format

```
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s
```

The extra_info content are not being printed.  I just get the following

```
2016/06/17 13:10:47 INFO test:
```

Comment: yeah it was a just typo, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [`logging docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), the `extra` keyword argument is used to add additional context to log records.

You can use info passed via `extra` parameter in the formatter by adding the dict key:

```
format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s - %(EXTRA_DICT_KEY)s'
```

*Note that if you set up formatter like this and forget to pass the dict key, you'll get a string formatting exception.*

---

As you can see in your example, you haven't specified any key in the formatter.

So, instead of:

```
format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'
```

Try:

```
format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s - %(test)s'
```

---

- You may find some other useful info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug).

Comment: Ok thank you I miss-read that section for some in thinking that it was just added through the message.  So basically what I need to do is like in my example add %(test)s and it would work.  Thanks so much.

Comment: How can you generalize this approach to print any extra key/value pair that is passed? --> Essentially, I want the logger to have a generic format (**kwargs-style) that will print any `extra` dict, without having to define the key name a priori (does not have to be `test`)